# Changing the color of points in scatter plot for different dummy values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

In my dataset, I have a `Price` column for house prices and 5 dummy columns for different locations in the city. What I want to do is to show data points on the scatter plot with different colors.

For instance, on a scatter plot including all the prices of the houses, I want to have:

- Red for all price points when `dummy1` which indicates house being in `Area1` is equal to 1.
- Blue for all price points when `dummy2` which indicates house being in `Area2` is equal to 2.

and so on until the last column. How can I create that plot? I can create the scatter plot without the color using `plt.scatter()` but don't know how to add the color code.

Comment: Can we see at least the header of your data! few first lines of columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the docs for [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) which describes a parameter `c`, which can be

> A sequence of color specifications of length n.

Here is an example, which creates 100 random `x` and `y` data points. If `y` value is over `5`, the point will be blue, else red as specified in `c` list.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

x = list(range(100))
y = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(len(x))]
c = ["b" if y > 5 else "r" for y in y]

plt.scatter(x, y, c=c)
plt.show()
```

The output will look like this:

[image]